# Which are the possibilities to save and load data?

Tags: json, dart, yaml

I want to save some data to the file and to load them later. On the [Dart API Reference](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#home) and the [Articles](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/) websites I've found only the JSON format. For some reasons I always use YAML, so my question is simple:

**Is it possible to use YAML for saving and loading data? And how if it is?**

And because of my curiosity:

**What other data storing formats are supported?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [YAML *PARSER*](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/yaml) (so only reading!) available.

If you want to use [BSON (Binary JSON)](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bson), then you can choose this package.

Another alternative would be [protobuf](http://github.com/dart-lang/dart-protobuf), allows binary and JSON.

And then there is as always [XML](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml) for both loading and storing.

There are maybe more solutions available, take a look at the [pub package manager](https://pub.dartlang.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like what I've looked for. Parsing is more important than writing (and writing can be easily done with forEach from Map and dart:io library I think), so the YAML parser library, you mentioned, is sufficient to me at the moment.